# Slow loading Wordpress website after database import

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I recently imported a Wordpress database and, after a few issues, managed to get it imported as it should be. However, now that the import has taken place, there seems to be an issue on the front-end, where the site takes an abnormal amount of time to load the page.

The back-end loads with normal speed, i just cannot for the life of me figure out what's causing the loading speed issue on the front-end.

Site in question: http://telikin.com.au/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took 375ms on my PC. According to firebug (firefox plugin) its wp-ui/css/css.php plugin which is taking too long to load. Also if browser do not find files on request it keep trying which also slow the speed of website.

Comment: Thanks for the response, not sure what's causing the issue on my end, but it's something i need to investigate obviously.